# DataGrid, постраничный вывод и сортировка

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть самописный класс для обработки постраничного вывода. Суть его в том, что ему передается функция для вывода элементов текущей страницы и он ее использует при обращении к текущему списку элементов

Есть DataGrid с фиксированным набором столбцов, которые берут данные из объекта коллекции, которая получается из экземпляра класса, описанного выше.

Теперь вопрос, как определить сортировку?

Пытался использовать обработку события `DataGrid.Sorting`, но столкнулся с парочкой проблем

1. В аргументы передается текущая сортировка, а не та, которая будет. Хотя ее можно просчитать, думаю, это может вызвать артефакты в дальнейшем
2. При смене коллекции элементов (перелистывании страницы) сортировка на столбцах сбрасывается, что печально. То есть сортировка, которая реализована в функции получения элементов остается (столбец отсортирован), а иконка сортировки с заголовка столбца пропадает

Подскажите выход

Answer (score 1):

А какой класс если не секрет "для обработки постраничного вывода".

Что не так со стандартным свойством VirtualMode? там и сортировка вроде бы поддерживается... 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Это Winforms, а у меня WPF. Но дело не в этом даже. Предложите способ виртуализации для схемы Клиент - Сервер - СерверБД

Comment: В данном случае Сервер должен иметь возможность выдавать данные порциями, или же загружать все данные во временный буфер в приложении, а на экран выводить порциями...